# Examples of languages that distinguish fewer modal categories in the negative than they do in the affirmative

Tags: negation

Are there any languages that distinguish fewer modal categories in the negative than they do in the affirmative?

---

I can think of one example of a language, Burmese, that appears to show fewer tense-aspect distinctions in the negative than in the affirmative, but I'm curious whether there are any examples of a similar phenomenon for mood.

According to [this chapter on symmetric and assymetric negation](https://wals.info/chapter/113), Burmese has a negative particle that partially occupies the slot taken by a tense-aspect particle.

I can't tell based on the article or the original dissertation whether the morpheme bí (glossed as PERF) is perfective or perfect.

```
θwâ-dé
go-ACTUAL
((s)he) goes/went.

θwâ-mé
go-POTENTIAL
((s)he) will go.

θwâ-bí
go-PERF
((s)he) has gone.

ma-θwâ-bû
NEGATIVE-go-NEGATIVE
((s)he) does/did/will not go, has not gone
```

The original source of the examples [is this dissertation](https://wals.info/refdb/record/Cornyn-1944).

The dissertation is available on [Wikimedia commons here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cornyn_Outline_of_Burmese_Grammar.pdf).

[Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f5/Cornyn_Outline_of_Burmese_Grammar.pdf) is the PDF and the data is on page 13 by internal numbering (15 by PDF numbering).

Comment: What do you mean by 'modal categories'? Is it only tense-aspect-mood or person and number are also included? In the latter case, Estonian is an example, since Estonian verbs distinguish 3 persons × 2 numbers = 6 affirmative forms in each tense, but there's a single negative form of each tense, no person or number is distinguished in the negative.

Comment: By `modal categories` I meant distinct moods. For example, a language with a distinction between the imperative and indicative moods in the affirmative but not the negative would count as an example of this. Now that I think about it, Burmese itself might count as example if the potential (which is glossed as a realis future in English) really is irrealis.